Binding a negative number parameter returns no results
I'm trying to retrieve some data which I don't have control over from Snowflake using the Node.js SDK.
The data has a signed numeric column. I'm trying to query for records where the value of that column is equal to a given parameter.
SELECT
COLUMN A,
COLUMN B
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE
MY_COLUMN = 12345 / -12345;

If I run this query directly in the browser in a worksheet on app.snowflake.com, I get the results as expected where the value of MY_COLUMN is positive or negative.
However, if I make a query from the Node SDK with a bound parameter, the positive parameter returns the expected results, whereas the negative parameter returns no results (with no error).
If I remove the parameter binding and just include the negative parameter directly in the SQL query, I do get the values as expected. Is this a bug with the SDK, or is there something else I'm missing here?

For queries run directly in the UI, it's shown as in the question.
For queries from the SDK, it shows the same with a ? where the parameter should be.
